# How to configure several proxies in ubuntu server

Tags: apt, server, lubuntu, proxy

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 1804 bionic in server version. During the install process I configured a proxy like http://x.x.x.x:xxxx. The problem now is for the moment that proxy is not longer available and I want to change to another external proxy.

I've tried already with changing the apt.conf file with the Acquire option and the export option on command line but every time I execute an apt command it still working with the old proxy configuration.

Where is store this proxy configuration asked in during the installation process

Is ther a way to configure *an in-case-of-fail* proxy? this to manage several proxy server and make the connection with the first in being available.

How can I change that initial configuration from the installation process.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the contents of /etc/apt/apt.conf.d directory, maybe there is another file with the (old) proxy settings there.

Comment: The file is 90curtin-aptproxy. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to configure the fail-proxy?